# Javascript String Length Differs From PHP mb_strlen

Tags: php, javascript

I use `document.getElementById("text").value.length` to get the string length through javascript, and `mb_strlen($_POST['text'])` to get the string length by PHP and both differs very much. Carriage returns are converted in javascript before getting the string length, but I guess some characters are not being counted.

For example,

> [b]15. Umieszczanie obrazka z logo na stronie zespołu[/b]

This block of text is calculated 57 in javascript and 58 in PHP. When the text gets long, the difference increases. Is there any way to overcome this?

Comment: What encoding are you working with on JavaScript side?

Comment: Can you make an example with more differences than just one (which could be down to counting line breaks or whatever)? Presumably, the more special characters like `ł` you use, the gap will widen.

Comment: Have you tried using the optional second argument to specify an encoding? I assume you've transcribed the sample to us ascii and that the real string is not.

Comment: What is the optional second argument to specify an encoding?

Comment: Oh yeah, I'm using UTF-8 encoding. Is there a special way to calculate the string length for it?

Comment: Try `mb_strlen($_POST['text'], "UTF-8")`

Comment: Nothink to do with mb_ etc... Here TheOnly92 has a difference of only 1 because his text has.... one line! If you type a two lines text, you'll get a difference of 2... and so on. JS length don't take account of EOL when PHP count them.

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to get the length of an UTF-8 encoded string in PHP, you should specify the encoding in the second parameter of `mb_strlen`, like so:

```
mb_strlen($_POST['text'], 'UTF-8')
```

Also, don't forget to call `stripslashes` on the POST-var.

Answer (score 2):

I have found an mb_strlen equivalent function for Javascript, maybe this might be useful for someone else:

```
function mb_strlen(str) {
    var len = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        len += str.charCodeAt(i) < 0 || str.charCodeAt(i) > 255 ? 2 : 1;
    }
    return len;
}
```

Thanks to all that tried to help!

Comment: Who knew that multi byte characters were encoded using 3 bytes?! First time I heard of it..

Comment: @PP It is of course incorrect and the function will only work for mixes of characters either in the 0-127 range or in a character set that doesn't fit in two. I really thing @TheOnly92 should solve it right instead.

Comment: @TheOnly92: All characters that needs two bytes to be represented as UTF-8 will take two bytes, all that needs three bytes will take three bytes and those who takes four bytes will take four bytes, etc, etc. The limit between 2 and 3 should be much higher than 2048 though.

Comment: @Fredrik Well then, what do you suggest to make the function more perfect?

Comment: @TheOnly92 You either need to do proper UTF-8 decoding and count the bytes or you shouldn't do it at all because javascript already calculate the length correctly for you. If you want the length to be correct in php you should call mb_strlen() with the correct arguments there, just like you have already got answers explaining.

Comment: Okay, what is the proper way of UTF-8 decoding for javascript? I'm counting bytes with PHP as well.

Comment: string.length /2 may always give the byte count in javascript, though I haven't tried this. Javascript uses UCS-2 encoding internally and string.length returns the number of UCS-2 code units in the string, *not* the number of characters.

Answer (score 0):

I notice that there is a non-standard character in there (the ł) - I'm not sure how PHP counts non-standard - but it could be counting that as two. What happens if you run the test without that character?

Comment: Without that it is accurate, I have already been suspecting that it is about the encoding... Is there an equivalent function for Javascript?

Comment: @TheOnly92, why do you want to fix it in the end that is doing it correct already? Isn't it better to tell the PHP end how it should calculate the length correctly (see the Matthew's comment to your question).

Comment: The fact is my database storage collation doesn't take utf8 into account I think, it counts those character lengths as 2...

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
function mb_strlen (s) {
  return ~-encodeURI(s).split(/%..|./).length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just type more than one line in your text area and you'll see the diference going bigger and bigger...
This came from the fact Javascript value.length don't count the end of line when all PHP length functions take them in account.
Just do:

```
// In case you're using CKEditot
// id is the id of the text area
var value = eval('CKEDITOR.instances.'+id+'.getData();');

// String length without the CRLF   
var taille = value.length;

// get number of line
var nb_lines = (value.match(/\n/g) || []).length;

// Now, this value is the same you'll get with strlen in PHP
taille = taille + nb_lines;
```