# Javascript String Length Differs From PHP mb_strlen (on textarea row, line breaks)

Tags: php, javascript, string-length

I am using JavaScript as well as PHP to calculate string lengths. Everything is OK except when I calculate a textarea string length coming from Chrome or Firefox versus Internet Explorer. New textarea rows/linebreaks are calculated as 2 chars in Internet Explorer and PHP. But Chrome and Firefox calculate textarea rows/linebreaks just as 1 char (versus PHP and Internet Explorer calculates as 2). This is my problem. Anyone knows how to resolve it?

So JavaScript char count in a textarea in IE = the string length calculated with PHP
/// And JavaScript char count in a textarea in Chrome/Firefox does not equal the string length calculated with PHP.

Code used:

```
Javascript  :  document.getElementById("text").value.length

PHP  :  mb_strlen($_POST['text'], 'UTF-8')
```

There are other posts about this, mainly the following one: [Javascript String Length Differs From PHP mb_strlen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482907/javascript-string-length-differs-from-php-mb-strlen) . But the answer to my question is not there and couldn't find it on any other posts.

Thanks for your help and suggestions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Firefox and Chrome use only `\n` for linebreaks while IE(opera too) uses `\r\n`

To get unique results replace all occurrences of  `\r\n` by `\n` before counting the string-length