# Enforce a maximum byte count in an HTML textarea field

Tags: php, html, textarea

I'm trying to limit the number of entered unicode characters in a textarea to 500.
When I try to post the form and get the textarea content to check its length in the back-end, I get a double length, meaning the value I get from strlen is twice the number of the inputted characters.

What is the problem here?

```
<textarea id="ArticleSummary" name="ArticleSummary" rows="4" maxlength="500">
 <?php echo $Summary; ?></textarea>
  $Summary = trim( $_POST['ArticleSummary'] );
  echo strlen($Summary);
```

Comment: Does `mb_strlen()` give a better result?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, that's it. strlen() was counting every unicode character twice. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unicode characters take 2 bytes each and strlen returns the number of bytes in the string, you can transform it to unicode characters and check the length.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where from you are taking variable $Summary;but if it is longer than your required 500 signs it will be sent as is. Example code below:

```
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<?php empty($_POST['ArticleSummary']) or var_dump(mb_strlen($_POST['ArticleSummary']));?>
<form method="POST" action="">
<?php $text = '123456789'; ?>

<textarea id="ArticleSummary" name="ArticleSummary" rows="4" maxlength="5"><?php echo $text;?></textarea>

<input value="submit" type="submit" />

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but it was a top result in Google. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7642371/470480) about line breaks **\n** in html/JavaScript and **\r\n** in PHP.

Also note that you want to use `mb_strlen` because certain characters, like emoji, will count as multiple characters in PHP.

Here is the solution:

```
// <textarea maxlength="2500">...</textarea>

echo strlen( $text ); // 5132 (incorrect)
echo mb_strlen( $text ); // 2566 (incorrect)

$text = preg_replace( "/\r\n|\r/", "\n", $text );

echo mb_strlen($order_notes); // 2500 (correct)
```

Comment: [See the metacharacter: `\R`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7836692/2943403)