# Why HTML maxlength and PHP mb_strlen is showing different count number?

Tags: php, html

In my php page I have **textarea** input box where I want to limit the characters up to **1000** only.

For that, first I am using HTML **maxlength** and then valid the length using PHP `mb_strlen` too but both PHP and HTML counting is not equal.

**For example:**

**Here is my text:**

> Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It
>   has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making
>   it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at
>   Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure
>   Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going
>   through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the
>   undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and
>   1.10.33 of 'de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum' (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the
>   theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line
>   of Lorem Ipsum, 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..', comes from a line in
>   section 1.10.32.
>
> The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced
>   below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from 'de
>   Finibus Bonorum et Malorum' by Cicero are also reproduced in their
>   exact original form, accompaniedd

Now, In that HTML textarea box, I just copy and past that text and then press the submit button to validate the text using PHP.

But PHP is showing me 1002 characters? Why? The HTML maxlength should be limit the text up to 1000 characters so my PHP code should not be showing the 1002 characters error message.

**PHP code:**

```
$data =  rtrim($data);
echo mb_strlen($data); // 1002 characters
```

Is there any mistake? How can I solve it?

Thank You.

**Updated:**

```
$data = "Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of 'de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum' (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..', comes from a line in section 1.10.32.

The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from 'de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum' by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompaniedd";

$data =  trim($data);
echo mb_strlen($data);
?>

<textarea maxlength="1000" cols="100" rows="20"></textarea>
```

and Output is 1002 characters!

[image]

**Finally, Can you tell me what is best solution to limit the textarea length?**

Comment: This string doesn't seem to have multi byte characters and for me both strlen() and mb_strlen() return 1000 for it.

Comment: @marekful I have uploaded 2 image. Please check that. It's showing me 1002 characters.

Comment: Please don't post code as an image. Copy/paste the code into the question itself.

Comment: okay. I have updated again with code.

Comment: When I try your code, I get 1000, not 1002: https://3v4l.org/HRI6h

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I have uploaded a Image that is showing me 1002 characters.

Comment: Sure, but then there's something else going on that we don't know about since we are unable to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Okay, Thanks.

Comment: Now, it's solved the error using this code: `$data =  preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $data);` In my string there was line break.

Answer (score 0):

`$data = trim($data);`

use `strlen($data);`

Better you use jquery for 1000 chars restriction. It will not reload whole page.

Comment: Why would you include a 100kb bloated library like jQuery when you could do the same in a couple of rows in pure js?

Comment: most of the websites uses jquery nowadays.

Comment: So what? If the OP already is using jQuery (which we don't know), fine, but if the OP isn't, then using jQuery for this is silly. People should learn the baisc language instead of bloating their sites with a bunch of bloated libraries for super simple and small features. My point is that directly going to _"use jQuery"_, no matter what the issue is, is a bad habit. http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but it was the first result in Google. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7642371/470480) about line breaks **\n** in html/JavaScript and **\r\n** in PHP.

Also to clarify, you need `mb_strlen` because certain characters, like emoji, will count as multiple characters in PHP.

Here is the solution:

```
echo strlen( $text ); // 5132 (incorrect due to emoji)
echo mb_strlen( $text ); // 2566 (incorrect due to linebreaks)

$text = preg_replace( "/\r\n|\r/", "\n", $text );

echo mb_strlen($order_notes); // 2500 (correct)
```