# Check length by characters like mb_strlen in JS

Tags: javascript

Do you know how to check length by characters in JS like mb_strlen function in PHP? I've just known use this way and it counts byte not characters. Thank you so much!

> $(".textarea").val().length

Comment: You should share some of your html (what is "element" ?), or examples of strings for which there is the  issue.

Comment: Thank you. I mean element is any jquery selector.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript String Length Differs From PHP mb\_strlen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482907/javascript-string-length-differs-from-php-mb-strlen)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using UTF-8, I guess that the following function will work for you,
as it should replace all multiple-byte characters and then get the length:

```js
function countChars(str) {
  return str.replace(/[\u0080-\u10FFFF]/g, "x").length;
}

console.log(countChars('abc abc abc'));
```

(Documentation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description)

---

Another way of doing it could be to use `.split('')` and get the length of the array:

```js
function countChars(str) {
  return str.split('').length;
}

console.log(countChars('abc abc abc'));
```

Anyway, I'd like you to give examples of strings to see it working!

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm using UTF8-mb4 (for display Japanese and Vietnamese). Its work for me. But I tried with more Japanese characters with, 3000 and its not right. It counts 2976. Here is my sample https://docs.google.com/document/d/1tWKr4atGHrtlsJg-i3Yisj0GAicWDiCdro3ACPI5-YQ/edit?usp=sharing