# php strlen returning incorrect values

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm using laravel 5.7, and i decided to play with some strings, here comes my problem, basically, my code in my controller goes like this.

```
$from = strlen($request->from);

$to  = strlen($request->to);
  
return array('from_len' => $from, 'to_len'=>$to);
```

what I'm sending in postman is like this

```
"direction" : true,
"to" : "",
"from" : "‬"
```

and what return is this

```
{
 "from_len": 3,
 "to_len": 0
}
```

So yeah i don't understand what is happening.

Thanks in advance for your attention people.

Comment: Have you tried including the values it thinks it's working with in the response - `$request->from` etc.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482907/javascript-string-length-differs-from-php-mb-strlen

Comment: `var_dump($request->from);`

Comment: ok people thanks for the answer i was using dd() for checking the strings, and the $to was null but $from was a empty string, right now, is just working, still dunno why was failing, I'm still trying to reproduce the error, if it happens again ill let you know.